# Ubuntu cannot recognize the Graphics Card after installing it alongside Windows

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

Following are the two drivers on my system:

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau

$ lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3978]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
    Memory at d1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [8086:0c0c] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3978]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 35

$ sudo lshw -numeric -C display
[sudo] password for animesh: 
  *-display               
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] [10DE:1392]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation [10DE]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:36 memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:b2000000-b207ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:416]
       vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:33 memory:d1000000-d13fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

I am not sure if my primary driver is the Intel one or the Nvidia one?

I am running Ubuntu as dual boot alog with Windows 10 which has Nvidia as the default driver.

I wanted to confirm this before moving on with the installation of CUDA.

Comment: Just guessing here, but I would think that if Windows 10 defaulted to NVIDIA, then you should install the NVIDIA driver into Ubuntu.  Have you tried adding the `graphics-drivers` ppa and install the NVIDIA drivers that way?  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

Comment: @Terrance I did that but after restart I got a black screen. I did hear that drum sound when ubuntu starts up but it is showing a black screen. What should I do?

Comment: I removed the drivers. The issue was solved. Luckily that did not remove cuda.

Comment: Ah, glad you got it fixed then.  Sorry I couldn't get back till later.